# Multiple generic parameter type inference not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

```
export class OneParam {
    static bar<P1>(q:any, params: { p1: P1 }) {}
}

OneParam.bar('foo', { p1: 12 });
```

In the above block of code, `P1` is correctly inferred and does not need to be explicitly passed in, where as here:

```
export class TwoParams {
    static bar<T, P1>(q:T ,params: { p1: P1 }) {}
}

TwoParams.bar<string>('foo', { p1: 12 });
```

The second parameter is not inferred. Is this a bug with the typescript inference or simply a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on purpose as you can read here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

I extracted the interesting part:

[...]

Once we’ve written the generic identity function, we can call it in one of two ways. The first way is to pass all of the arguments, including the type argument, to the function:

```
let output = identity<string>("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
```

Here we explicitly set T to be string as one of the arguments to the function call, denoted using the <> around the arguments rather than ().

The second way is also perhaps the most common. Here we use type argument inference – that is, we want the compiler to set the value of T for us automatically based on the type of the argument we pass in:

```
let output = identity("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
```

Notice that we didn’t have to explicitly pass the type in the angle brackets (<>); the compiler just looked at the value "myString", and set T to its type.

*While type argument inference can be a helpful tool to keep code shorter and more readable, you may need to explicitly pass in the type arguments as we did in the previous example when the compiler fails to infer the type,* **as may happen in more complex examples.**

[...]

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for the research and answer!

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: It's not clear that this is "on purpose", when the compiler fails to infer from more complicated types. Could it just be a technical limitation or feature not yet implemented?